# Convert a string to Yaml in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have an helm chart used to deploy a spring service that have configuration file in YAML file. Currently, my helm chart use the following code:

**templates/configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: account-service-config
data:
  variable.yml:
    {{ range $key, $value := .Values.spring.config.content | indent 4  }}
                            {{ $key | indent 2}}={{ $value }}
                                {{printf "\n" }}
                            {{- end -}}
```

I have a ***values.yaml*** as below

```
spring:
  config:
    content: |-
      spring:
        application:
          name: hello
        security:
              abc:
                abc-def: ${url}
```

The problem is that if I want to change the value of anything for e.g application name, I have to rewrite the entire configuration like that:

```
spring:
  config:
    content: |-
      spring:
        application:
          name: valuechange
        security:
              abc:
                abc-def: ${url}
```

So my question is, is there a way to convert the string to Yaml in a Helm template. I wanted it to be converted into helm yaml and inject it through configmaps in deployment file.

The helm templates are common for many services so I cannot explicitly define the values as they are different for each service and I am overriding the values.yaml by another file called values.yaml in respective spring service repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function called `toYaml` like this:

```
  variable.yml: |-
{{ toYaml .Values.spring.config.content | indent 4 }}
```

We use something similar in our Hazelcast Helm Chart. Please check the details [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/master/stable/hazelcast/templates/config.yaml#L17).